# In a Jenkinsfile, how can I run a another Jenkinsfile in the same Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

[image]

This repo has three Jenkinsfile in different path. I want to call Jenkinsfiles in different directories in the Jenkinsfile of the root directory and execute them in the same Job. Is there any way can do this? The code is the Jenkinsfile of the root directory.

```
pipeline{
    agent { label "x86_64" }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir('python3/python3.6.8')
                    script {
                        def Changes6 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git diff --name-only ${env.GIT_COMMIT} ${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT} | grep servicelayer | wc -l").trim()
                        if (Changes6=="0") {
                            //TODO: How to trigger the python3/python3.6.8/centos_7.7_1908/build/Jenkinsfile and run in this Job?
                        }
                    }
                dir('python3/python3.7.9') {
                    script {
                        def Changes7 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git diff --name-only ${env.GIT_COMMIT} ${GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT} | grep servicelayer | wc -l").trim()
                        if (Changes7=="0") {
                            //TODO: How to trigger the python3/python3.7.9/centos_7.7_1908/build/Jenkinsfile and run in this Job?
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create second job for the second jenkinsfile and trigger it from the first pipeline.

```
build(job: 'foo', parameters: [password('parameter-name', 'secret-value')])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to use one job